# !@DumpState : debug level:0x4f4c on BOOT_COMPLETE on apk 26 +

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a service starting when my phone is booting. The goal is to get stats of the sytem without the need to have an UI.
But since I raised my min apk from 16 to 26, my BroadcastReceiver does not work anymore.
Here my Reciever :

```
public class OnBootServiceStart extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Debug receiver", "Boot effectué");

            try {
                sleep(1000 * 10);
                Log.d("Debug receiver", "sleep");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent i = new Intent("com.example.project.BackgroundTimer");
            i.setClass(context, BackgroundTimer.class);
            context.startService(i);
        }
}
```

As you can see, I put an sleep func to check for debug. But my logcast drop this when I restart my phone and stop the process ( launch the app on a Samsug A40 ) :

```
27 10:05:27.804 4790-4790/? D/DebugConfigStorage: DebugConfigStorage()
2021-04-27 10:05:28.974 4790-4790/? D/DebugConfigStorage: DebugConfigStorage()
2021-04-27 10:06:36.456 10821-10821/com.example.project D/Debug receiver: Boot effectué
2021-04-27 10:06:36.457 10821-10821/com.example.project D/Debug receiver: sleep
2021-04-27 10:06:46.498 4300-10420/? D/Debug: !@DumpState : SHIP
2021-04-27 10:06:46.498 4300-10420/? D/Debug: !@DumpState : debug level:0x4f4c
2021-04-27 10:06:46.498 4300-10420/? D/Debug: !@Dumpstate : Finally, system will skip dumpstate
```

I search almost everywhere but didn't found how to get my boot complete and what / why is there `!@DumpState`
If someone can help me I will be really gratefull.
Thanks!

Here is the squeleton of my app :

```
Service :

public class BackgroundTimer extends IntentService {

    private final static String TAG = "BackgroundTimer";

    // Constructeur du service
    public BackgroundTimer() {

        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("Debug" + TAG, "start réussi");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, START_STICKY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.d("Debug" +TAG, "passage réussi");
        int tempsAttente = 1000*10*1;
        Log.d("Debug" +TAG, "pré boucle");

        while (true) {
            try {
                sleep(tempsAttente);
                Log.d("Debug" +TAG, "boucle réussi");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main Activity ( the Service call is working here ) :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d("Debug OnCreate", "lancement app");
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundTimer.class);
        startService(i);
        Log.d("Debug OnCreate", "lancement service");

        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundTimer.class);
        startService(i);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.project">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Project">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.example.project.BackgroundTimer" android:permission="true" android:process=":newProcess">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.project.BackgroundTimer" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.project.OnBootServiceStart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```